# Node on Linux thinks its out of date

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, ubuntu

I have a couple of Discord bots running on a VPS (Ubuntu) and I am using Docker to deploy them into containers. Both of these bots are running fine, so I am trying to launch a third one for something else. I have set it up the exact same way, however when I try and run the container, the bot logs into Discord, but then this error pops up and the app stops.

```
Your node version is currently 12.20.0
Please update it to a version >= 14.x.x from https://nodejs.org/
```

My other apps are running fine on version 12.20.0 so I am not sure what the issue is. If I have to update I will, but I don't know how to update Node on Linux.

This is the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.20.0

# Create the directory!
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/bot
WORKDIR /usr/src/bot

# Copy and Install our bot
COPY package.json /usr/src/bot
RUN npm install

# Our precious bot
COPY . /usr/src/bot

# Start me!
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Comment: Are you using your own image based on the official Nodejs image? If that is the case just update the tag of the nodejs image in your Dockerfile and rebuild the image.  If you are currently using latest (instead of an actual tagged version) then just pull the node image and rebuild your image.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what any of that means, I am very new to Linux.

Comment: Ok, so look in your repo. Do you have a Dockerfile? If so, post it here and we can go from there. The bottom line is that your image is using an old version of node and needs to be updated.

Comment: @camba1 I have just added my Dockerfile to my question.

Comment: The first line in your docker file (FROM node:12.20.0) indicates which version of the official nodejs image you are using. In this case you are using nodejs 12.20. Now you need to update to at least version nodejs version 14 as per the error message. Docker hub shows versions 14.15.5 & 15.9.0 are available, so update your docker file with one of those in the first line. Then rebuild your image with docker build, test you app and if it is still working you can deploy it.

Comment: Ohh, that is so simple. Thanks for explaining!